# Redirect programatically using Regex in next.config.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My website is changing URL structure and I have 1000s of pages. For SEO I would like to set up a Regex redirect in my next.config.js file, but the official documentation doesn't really help my case because my pages have the following structure:

```
/product-name-price/
```

The new structure will be:

```
/price/product-name
```

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to get `/product-name-price` to redirect to `/price/product-name-price` with the following changes to next.config.js:

```
async redirects() {
return [
{
source: '/:product',
destination: '/price/:product',
permanent: true,
}
]
}
```

How do I manipulate the `:product` parameter within the next.config.js file to exclude the `-price` part of `product-name-price` so that my final url will be `/price/product-name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this using middleware since it doesn't seem to be possible to modify the parameter of the redirect destination in next.config.js.

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.endsWith('-price') || request.nextUrl.pathname.endsWith('-price/')) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/price/${request.nextUrl.pathname.split("-price")[0]}`, request.url), 308)
  }
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('price.php')) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/price/${request.url.split("price.php?brand=")[1].toLowerCase()}`, request.url), 308)
  }
}
```

The first conditional checks if the request pathname ends with `-price`, and then redirects to the same path without `-price` by splitting the string, with status code 308.

The second conditional checks to see if the request pathname contains `price.php`, in which case it also has query parameter of 'brand'. It takes the value of this parameter and redirects to the `/price/product-name` structure, where 'product-name' is equal to the value of 'brand', again by splitting the string.

I have used 308 redirect for SEO purposes, to indicate it is a permanent redirect to Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using RegEx in your `next.config`: [Regex Path Matching](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#regex-path-matching)

It will be something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:product-name(.*)-:price(\\d)',
        destination: '/:price/:product-name',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

@user3536141, I can try to help you with a more accurate example if you provide the use case and its variations (if there is some).